# How to count capital letters with compareTo() method?

Tags: java, string

Is there a way to count capital letters in a string using the method `compareTo()`? This is my current code so far, I don't know what to add in the `if` statement.

```
import java.util.*;
public class countcapitalletters 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("enter a string");
                String input = scan.nextLine();
                int count = 0;
                for(int i=0; i<=input.length()-1; i++)
                {
                   if(input.substring(i,i+1)
                    {
                        count = count+1;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(count);

    }
}
```

i dont know what to add to my if statement.

Comment: Please share your code in order to get the answer

Comment: java compareto example: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=10

Comment: ok i added my code.

Comment: The string `input.substring(i, i+1)` contains a character the input. `s.compareTo("A") >= 0` would say the string is _greater or equal_ to A. Combined with the logical **and** operator `&&` you should be able to accomplish the task.

Comment: @Saravana Edit rejected. `Comparator` doesn't have a `compareTo()` method. Edit was totally invalid.

Comment: you can just use `string.replaceAll("[^A-Z]+", "").length()`

Comment: @YCF_L He can use a large number of things, but the *assignment* requires him to use `compareTo()`. Read the question.

Comment: thank you @EJP I know, I just provide a second plan that's all :)

Answer (score 1):

You can write a method as follows:

```
public int countUpperCase(String input) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        String currentChar = input.substring(i, i + 1);
        if (currentChar.compareTo("A") >= 0 && currentChar.compareTo("Z") <= 0) {
            count = count + 1;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: But you haven't tested it. This does not compile.

Comment: It's tested now.